# Google's +1 functionality within Android application

Tags: android

I was wondering is it possible to add an +1 button (Facebook 'like' equivalent) within your Android application/game which in result would redirect the action to the +1 button displayed on the application/game page on Google Market? Is it possible, any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ platform for Android now offers a native +1 button for Android applications.

For more information, see:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#recommend_content_with_the_1_button

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself: There's no such API at the time being.

Comment: The G+ API has just been released for android at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#recommend_content_with_the_1_button